# How to count the number of characters in a line, except a specific character?

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

This is part file

```
N W N N N N N N N N N
N C N N N N N N N N N
N A N N N N N N N N N
N N N N N N N N N N N
N G N N N N N N N N N
N C N N N C N N N N N
N C C N N N N N N N N
```

In each line I want to count the total number of all characters that are not "N"

my desire output

```
1
1
1
0
1
2
2
```

Comment: Use ``sed`` to replace stuff you don't care about and ``awk`` to count the remaining length ``sed 's/N//g ; s/\s//g' file | awk '{ print length($0); }'``

Answer (score 13, accepted):

GNU **awk** solution:

```
awk -v FPAT='[^N[:space:]]' '{ print NF }' file
```

- `FPAT='[^N[:space:]]'` - the pattern defining a field value (any character except `N` char and whitespace)

---

The expected output:

```
1
1
1
0
1
2
2
```

Answer (score 9):

```
awk '{ gsub("[ N]",""); print length() }'
```

Comment: can also use `awk '{print gsub(/[^ N]/,"")}'`

Answer (score 7):

Another `awk` approach (will return **-1** for empty lines).

```
awk -F'[^N ]' '$0=NF-1""' infile
```

Or in complex, it will return **-1** on empty lines, **0** on whitespaces (Tabs/Spaces) lines only.

```
awk -F'[^N \t]+' '$0=NF-1""' infile
```

Comment: will print `-1` for empty lines... but then that might be desirable to distinguish line made up of only N/space vs empty line...

Comment: @Sundeep Yes, that's correct. also see my update where lines was only contains Tabs or Spaces to indicate as 0

Answer (score 7):

assuming that count is needed for each line other than space character and `N`

```
$ perl -lne 'print tr/N //c' ip.txt 
1
1
1
0
1
2
2
```

- return value of `tr` is how many characters were replaced
- `c` to complement the set of characters given
- Note the use of `-l` option, strips newline character from input line to avoid off-by-one error and also adds newline character for the print statement

A more generic solution

```
perl -lane 'print scalar grep {$_ ne "N"} @F' ip.txt
```

- `-a` option to automatically split input line on white-spaces, saved in `@F` array
- `grep {$_ ne "N"} @F` returns array of all elements in `@F` which doesn't match the string `N`

  - regex equivalent would be `grep {!/^N$/} @F`
- use of `scalar` will give number of elements of the array

Answer (score 6):

Alternative **awk** solution:

```
awk '{ print gsub(/[^N[:space:]]/,"") }' file
```

- `gsub(...)` - The `gsub()` function returns the number of substitutions made.

---

The output:

```
1
1
1
0
1
2
2
```

Answer (score 5):

1. `tr` and *POSIX* shell script:

   ```
   tr -d 'N ' < file | while read x ; do echo ${#x} ; done
   ```
2. `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`:

   ```
   while read x ; do x="${x//[ N]}" ; echo ${#x} ; done < file
   ```

Comment: can use `awk '{print length()}'` to avoid the slower shell looping.. but then one could do it all with awk itself...

Comment: @Sundeep, It's true, (*if* both are started at the same time), that `awk` looping *is* faster than shell looping.  But the shell is always in memory, and `awk` might not be -- when `awk` is not already loaded, or swapped out, the overhead of loading it, ([the time lost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latency_(engineering))), can be greater than the advantage of running `awk` -- particularly on a small loop.  In such cases, (*i.e.* this case), `awk` can be *slower*.

Comment: well, am certainly not worried about time for small stuff... see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @Sundeep,  I *do* worry.  Some time ago I used to use [floppy based Linux distros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Floppy-based_Linux_distributions), which could run off a floppy, in a few megs of ram.  Needlessly using `awk` in a shell script could make such a system crawl on all fours.  Generally:  the same latency drag applies to systems in limited firmware, or any system under heavy load.

Answer (score 1):

A short combination of `tr` and `awk`:

```
$ tr -d ' N' <file.in | awk '{ print length }'
1
1
1
0
1
2
2
```

This deletes all spaces an Ns from the input file and `awk` just prints the length of each line.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way is to do it in python, which comes pre-installed in most of unix environments. Drop the following code in a .py file:

```
with open('geno') as f:
    for line in f:
        count = 0
        for word in line.split():
            if word != 'N':
                count += 1
        print(count)
```

And then do:

```
python file.py
```

From your terminal. What the above does is:

- for each line in a file named "geno"
- set a counter to 0 and increment it each time we find a value != 'N'
- when the end of the current line is reached, print the counter and go to the next line